# Use more than one Spring JpaTransactionManager in a controller?

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have a Spring MVC application using JPA 2.   All the controllers are annotated with @Transactional at the class level.

Is it possible to keep that annotation at the class level and simply override it with another @Transactional annotation at the method level?   I have one method I'd like to make SERIALIZABLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [multiple transaction managers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-multiple-tx-mgrs-with-attransactional) by adding qualifiers to distinguish which one that should be used, provided that they have been configured:

```
@Transactional("global")
public class SomeService {

    public void methodThatUsesTheGlobalTxManager() {
        // ...
    }

    @Transactional("special")
    public void methodThatUsesTheSpecialTxManager() {
        // ...
    }        
}
```

Comment: One final note:  After attempting to implement this, I found out the following:  JPA/Spring does not support custom isolation levels.   Oops.   org.springframework.transaction.InvalidIsolationLevelException: Standard JPA does not support custom isolation levels – use a special JpaDialect for your JPA implementation.

Comment: That said, you can still specify a vendor independent [Isolation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Isolation.html) level by setting the [isolation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-attransactional-settings) property of the `@Transactional` annotation.